# pyHook doesnt let me type

Tags: python, selenium, keyevent, pyhook

I am trying to detect global keypresses in python. (I am a complete noob in Python). My problem is that pyHook recognizes my key events but it doesn't let me type anymore. If I try to type something into the opened selenium webdriver (see code), nothing happens, except for the keyid being printed.

Here is my code:

```
import pyHook, pythoncom, sys, win32api
from colorama import Fore, init
from selenium import webdriver

add_key = 187 #keyID for "+" key
commands = ["start", "quit", "save", "help"]
urls = []
driver = webdriver.Chrome()

def OnKeyboardEvent(event):
    print(event.KeyID)
    if event.KeyID == add_key:
        print("add key pressed")
        urls.append(driver.current_url)
    return 0

def PrintHelpMessage():
    # write help message
    MainLoop()

def MainLoop():
    print(Fore.GREEN + "type commands for more help.")

    usr_input = input()
    if usr_input == "commands":
        print(Fore.GREEN + "available commands: start, quit, save, help")
        command_input = input()
        if command_input in commands:
            if command_input == "start":
                hook_manager = pyHook.HookManager()
                hook_manager.KeyDown = OnKeyboardEvent
                hook_manager.HookKeyboard()
                pythoncom.PumpMessages()
            elif command_input == "quit":
                sys.exit(0)
            elif command_input == "save":
                # implement save function
                print("Save function implemented soon")
            elif command_input == "help":
                PrintHelpMessage()


init(autoreset = True) # init colorama -> makes it possible to use colored text in terminal
print(Fore.RED + "---easy playlist manager---")
driver.get("http://youtube.com")
MainLoop()
```

Maybe someone can tell me how to fix it?

greetings

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're are returning `0` in `OnKeyboardEvent`, so the keyboard event is not passed to other handlers or the window itself. If you don't want to filter the event, you should return `True`.

See [Event Filtering](https://sourceforge.net/p/pyhook/wiki/PyHook_Tutorial/#event-filtering) in the documentation for more information.